# CORS problem after migrating ASP web api app from .netcore2.* to net6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Our code is falling foul of changes made during the upgrade from netcore2.* to netcore3.0 during our upgrade all the way to net6.0.

Following the guidlelines from the [MS Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) mean I now see this error in our client application:

`Access to fetch at <url1> from origin <url2> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Is there a way to achieve wildcard CORS with authentication?

### NEW code (net 6.0)

In `ConfigureServices`:

```
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc(o => o.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => { ... });
```

In `Configure`:

```
        app.UseCors(configurePolicy =>
        {
            configurePolicy.AllowAnyOrigin();
            configurePolicy.AllowAnyHeader();
            configurePolicy.AllowAnyMethod();
            //configurePolicy.AllowCredentials();  
        });

        app.UseMiddleware<OptionsMiddleware>();
        app.UseMiddleware<BearerTokenMiddleware>();

        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseMvc();
```

### OLD code (net 2.2) - working!

In `ConfigureServices`:

```
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => { ... });
```

In `Configure`:

```
        app.UseCors(configurePolicy =>
        {
            configurePolicy.AllowAnyOrigin();
            configurePolicy.AllowAnyHeader();
            configurePolicy.AllowAnyMethod();
            configurePolicy.AllowCredentials();
        });

        app.UseMiddleware<OptionsMiddleware>();
        app.UseMiddleware<BearerTokenMiddleware>();

        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseMvc();
```

Note the `AddMvc` changes above and the need to comment out `AllowCredentials` in `UseCors`.

Project type is `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`.

Comment: Sometimes a CORS error is actually covering up an error in the pipeline that occurs before the CORS policy is applied.

Comment: @SBFrancies this is absolutely spot on.   There is usage of EF here and the move from netcore 2.x to 3.0 changed things enough to cause a break which is presenting as a CORS error!.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The code I use is

```
app.UseRouting();    
app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
                .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials
```

It should work like this :D

Comment: No change to the result with that.  It still returns `... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: Does it returns okay through postman? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0 There might be something helpful here

Comment: See the comments on the question, SBFrancies has pointed out that there is an error in the pipeline presenting as a CORS issue.  However. your suggestion will still likely be good for when this has been overcome so thanks all the same.